# How to store tags from Bootstrap Tags Input field into my collection...?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using the ajduke:bootstrap-tagsinput` package and I'm trying to store the array in:

```
$('#dealTags').tagsinput('items')
```

in my deals collection, but the value of:

```
$(e.target).find('[name=dealTags]').val()
```

comes back as undefined. I'm a newbie to Meteor and Javascript, so sorry if this is a dumb question. Here is the form field:

```
<div class ="controls">
        <input id="dealTags" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add some tags..." data-role="tagsinput">
</div>
```

And here I try to insert the data to my collection in the Template

```
var deal = {
      dealTitle: $(e.target).find('[name=dealTitle]').val(),
      venueName: $(e.target).find('[name=venueName]').val(),
      when: $(e.target).find('[name=when]').val(),
      dealTags: $(e.target).find('[name=dealTags]').val()
};
```

And my collection method doing the actual writing to DB

```
Meteor.methods({
  dealInsert: function(dealAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(dealAttributes, {
      dealTitle: String,
      venueName: String,
      when: String,
      dealTags: String
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: where do you actually call the 'dealInsert' method? I don't see it. Also, what is the deal {} object about?  Please also add file names in which the code resides. I also think some code is missing, where do you deal with events?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just figured it out. It was the way I was reading the value of the input field. Changed this $(e.target).find('[name=dealTags]').val() to $('#dealTags').tagsinput('items') and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the *select* element instead of input to have val() return an array. (see [documentation](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/))

```
<div class ="controls">
    <select multiple id="dealTags" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add some tags..." data-role="tagsinput" />
</div>
```

Another solution is to keep using the *input* element, but call *.tagsinput('items')* instead of *val()*

```
var deal = {
  dealTitle: $(e.target).find('[name=dealTitle]').val(),
  venueName: $(e.target).find('[name=venueName]').val(),
  when: $(e.target).find('[name=when]').val(),
  dealTags: $(e.target).find('[name=dealTags]').tagsinput('items')
};
```